# TitleheaderForSection

Tags: objective-c

I want a TitleHeaderForSection after case 3 (example) (TableView).

Is Something like this possible:

```
Case 3:
TitleHeaderForSection = @"menu";
Break;
```

example:

```
Case 0

Case 1

Case 2

Case 3

MENU (TitleHeaderForSection)

Case 4

Case 5
```

i tried:

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

```
NSString *sectionHeader = nil;

if(section == 0) {
    sectionHeader = @"1";
}

if(section == 1) {
    sectionHeader = @"2";
}

if(section == 2) {
    sectionHeader = @"3";
}

return sectionHeader;
```

}

but only '1' is showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do something like that.  Why did you ask the question before trying it out?

If you return a string from [`[tableView: titleForHeaderInSection:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView%3atitleForHeaderInSection%3a), it will appear for the section it matches (in your case, 3).  Make sure to return nil for the other sections tho.  I've linked the `UITableViewDataSource` documentation for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will surely help you..

-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

```
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[lbl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:17]];
[lbl setTextColor:BROWN];
switch (section)
{
    case 0:  
        lbl.text = @" Name";
        break;
    case 1:  
        lbl.text = @" Quantity";
        break;
    case 2:  
        lbl.text = @" Amount";
        break;
}

return lbl;
```

}